# Memcached and Velocity

Tags: memcached, appfabric

I'm investigating using either Memcached or Velocity for distributed caching over a cluster of servers after reading Scott Hanselman's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479400/one-cache-for-various-applications). Does anybody know of a Microsoft web site that uses Velocity for its caching? If Microsoft aren't using it then does anybody know of any relatively popular web site that's using it?

Answer (score 3):

It would be pretty foolish for any substantial site to go live (in production) on a CTP of a product (***edit -*** good point in the comments - this isn't a hard rule... there are exceptions, for example stackoverflow). Velocity is currently in CTP2, which is good for building out proof-of-concept and planning for product releases, but that's all. Once it is a supported product, I'm sure we will see plenty of usage. Follow the Velocity product team blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/) for details.

As far as memcached vs Velocity, they have somewhat overlapping but ultimately different purposes. Memcached is *not* reliable. That is spelled out very clearly in the documentation and by the authors. It is intended to be blazingly fast, cheap to run and simple to administer. Velocity, on the other hand, is much more familiar to the formal enterprise software crowd. It is complex, with a robust API and is better for a more formal data environment.

Comment: While I agree with you in theory its amazing how many people go to production with beta / sub-1.0 releases of software. Its certainly prevalent in the LAMP / Open Source world. I cannot speak for the MSFT/ASP.NET world. Maybe we're more foolish! :)

Comment: @Cody it is not foolish in the open source world because you can easily evaluate the source and, if necessary, make the tweaks that fill in gaps where you need production-level stability. With a closed-source third party, what you get is what you get :)

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of simple OSS apps people use that they can "easily evaluate the source and ... make tweaks". Anything complex enough is not going to be something to just pickup and hack on for production, without significant resources.

Comment: "easily" is relative comparison between OSS and Microsoft products

Comment: Isn't this site (Stack Overflow) currently running on beta software?

Comment: @Guy this site is also in beta, with an atypical audience. You can always find exceptions to a guideline; that doesn't change the fact that it's still important to consider.

Comment: What beta software is stackoverflow running?

Answer (score 2):

memcached is not natively supported on Win32. There is a project that aims to port memcached to Win32

http://jehiah.cz/projects/memcached-win32/

And while they have been successful, they lag a couple of versions (point versions at this point) behind the main release line. So if you're on Win32 I think your best bet would be Velocity.

So while I dont have an answer to your question (what sites use Velocity) I think you're better off going with Velocity over memcached.